# Error in handling shape and fit of training set while using Multinomial Naive Bayes for Text classification

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have done all the preprocessing task like removing stopwords,HTML tags etc.
I am trying to classify IMDB movie dataset(Large Movie Review Datasets of Stanford Unoversity) using Multinomial Naive Bayes. I am getting error on varibable X. I have made into 2D array but don't know how to handle error?

This is part of code of Multinomial Naive Bayes.

```
categories = ['pos','neg']
         doc_to_train  = sklearn.datasets.load_files("/home/satyam/aclImdb_v1/aclImdb/train", description = None, categories = categories ,load_content=True,enco    ding='utf-8',shuffle=True,random_state=42)
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    X = (vectorizer.fit_transform(tokens).toarray())
    analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
    vect = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    y = np.array(doc_to_train.target)
    X = X.reshape()                 
    X = X.transpose()
    print (X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3)
    mnb=MultinomialNB().fit(X_train,y_train).predict(X_test)
    print ("MNB " %mnb)
    print ("Prediction " %mnb.predict(X_test))
    accuracy = mnb.score(X_test, y_test)
    print ("Accuracy " %accuracy)
```

Error encountered are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_analysis_NB.py", line 92, in <module>
    X = (vectorizer.fit_transform(tokens).toarray())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 943, in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 1130, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Please look for the path you have mentioned "/home/satyam/aclImdb_v1/aclImdb    /train" .  is right and contents are present in it.

Comment: Most likely you are getting error for `doc_to_train.shape`, you may need to look into `doc_to_train` before calling `.shape` on it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in this line:- `X=np.array([[doc_to_train.data], [doc_to_train.shape(25000,  12500)]])`?

Comment: Can you add your data?